# Create separate session for rails admin login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, rails-admin

I’m using **Rails 4.2.1** and **Devise** and **rails_admin** and I’m quite new to Rails.

I need to add **rails admin** to my project. I need a separate login For rails admin. (I don't want to add a new column user for that. As admin and normal users are different) For that I added a new model Admin. I used devise for creating views and models. But now I need to add routes in routes for admin user having only sign in feature(No need for registration). Now I have all those features(registration,...). I also need a separate session apart from the user session. As I logout user, adminuser is also logging out.

Comment: Please visit this [link](http://atmarkplant.com/rails-admin/). You should be able to have a good idea thereafter.

Comment: Its not administrator feature. Need to add railsadmin gem and add that feature to the project. So need an account for that, (not the user)

Comment: Can you share your routes ? User model and admin model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get seperate session please make changes in devise.rb

config.sign_out_all_scopes = false